# How to install Quadprog in Octave for windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: optimization, download, installation, octave

I have to use quadprog in Octave same as how it is used in Matlab.
While using quadprog in Octave this error was displayed

```
warning: the 'quadprog' function belongs to the optim package from Octave
 Forge
which seems to not be installed in your system.

Please read `http://www.octave.org/missing.html' to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.

error: 'quadprog' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

How to install Quadprog in Octave for windows 7 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pkg` command to install the package after downloading it. Check `doc pkg` for details